# What is the most complex game you know since 2014?

Tags: famous-players

Which classical top player chess game is the most complex since 2014 you know ?

A good candidate for such games are games with few pawns but many figures.

This year, Timman played a rather complicated game in Tata Steel. It was his only win
 in the B-group in this tournament.

Other examples ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Played a few days ago and commented upon on chess24, this game is quickly a real tactical mess:

```
rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1
[Event "European Individual Championship"]
[Site "Jerusalem ISR"]
[Date "2015.03.03"]
[EventDate "2015.02.24"]
[Round "7.6"]
[Result "1-0"]
[White "Liviu Dieter Nisipeanu"]
[Black "Ivan Bukavshin"]
[ECO "B48"]
[WhiteElo "2654"]
[BlackElo "2622"]
[PlyCount "137"]

1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 e6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nc6 5. Nc3 Qc7 6. Be3 a6
7. Qd2 Be7 8. O-O-O Nf6 9. f3 b5 10. Kb1 Ne5 11. g4 h6 12. Qg2
b4 13. Na4 d5 14. f4 Nexg4 15. Bc1 e5 16. fxe5 Nxe4 17. e6
Ngf2 18. Qxg7 Bf6 19. Nb5 Qxc2+ 20. Kxc2 Bxg7 21. Nc7+ Ke7
22. Nxd5+ Kxe6 23. Bg2 Be5 24. Rhe1 f5 25. Nc5+ Kf7 26. Nxe4
Nxe4 27. Bxe4 fxe4 28. Rxe4 Re8 29. Rf1+ Kg6 30. Nf4+ Bxf4
31. Rexf4 Bh3 32. Rg1+ Kh5 33. Rxb4 Re2+ 34. Kb3 Rf8 35. Rg3
Rxh2 36. Rb6 Rh8 37. Rxa6 Bg4 38. Rc3 Bf5 39. a4 Kg4 40. Rb6
Be4 41. Rf6 Re2 42. Ka3 Rd8 43. Bxh6 Rd1 44. Bc1 Bc2 45. Rf4+
Kh5 46. Rh3+ Kg6 47. Rg3+ Kh5 48. Rf8 Kh4 49. Rg7 Rd3+ 50. Ka2
Bb3+ 51. Ka1 Rd5 52. Rf1 Rd1 53. Rxd1 Bxd1 54. a5 Re4 55. Kb1
Ra4 56. Bd2 Bb3 57. Be1+ Kh5 58. Rb7 Be6 59. b4 Kg4 60. b5 Kf5
61. b6 Ra3 62. Kc2 Ra2+ 63. Kd3 Ke5 64. Re7 Ra3+ 65. Bc3+ Kd5
66. Rxe6 Kxe6 67. b7 Rb3 68. a6 Kd7 69. a7 1-0
```

Comment: That game was brutal.